# Include only posts with meta key “add_in_rss” in RSS Feed

Tags: php, rss

I edited [this file](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/feed-rss2.php) like this, but it doesn't work

```
    ...do_action( 'rss2_head' );

    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "add_in_rss", false);
        if($meta = "yes"){
        ?>
    <item>
        <title><?php the_title_rss(); ?><....
....
....p echo get_comments_number(); ?></slash:comments>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php rss_enclosure(); ?>

        <?php
        /**
         * Fires at the end of each RSS2 feed item.
         *
         * @since 2.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'rss2_item' );
        ?>
    </item>
    <?php } endwhile; ?>...
```

What is the mistake, how should it be right?

I am not a programmer. I entered this based on [this code](https://www.thewebtaylor.com/articles/wordpress-exclude-posts-with-meta-value) only removed the exclamation mark so that there would be a reverse trigger.

Sorry for My English.

Answer (score 1):

Change `if($meta = "yes")` to `if($meta == 'yes')`. Your way is setting the variable to yes, so it's always yes; the double equals symbol means to test for a condition rather than set it.